# Phonegap Filetransfer.download Ripple/Chrome

Tags: cordova

I am working on a mobile app using jquerymobile/phonegap/cordova(2.0). I try to download some files from a stream (xml) and store them locally. This behavior only appears in chrome browser, which I use for debugging (with ripple).

How do I start the chrome ? Here we go :

> /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-access

I'm developing at the Mac my plist file also has also an access * and I added `<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>` to my config.xml

I tried to download some pictures with following code :

```
function downloadImage(url,filename,use){
if(use==="thumb") {
    filename = filename + ".png";
    download(url, filename);
}return filename; }

function download(url, filename) {

//writeLog(window.appRootDir.fullPath);
ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.download(
    url,
    window.appRootDir.fullPath + "/" + filename,
    {},
    {});
}
```

On simulator works fine but in chrome it fails with following error :

```
TypeError
ripple.js:477
TypeError: Cannot call method 'download' of undefined
at n.exports.exec (chrome-extension://geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc/ripple.js:477:26724)
at FileTransfer.download (http://localhost/~binderf/www/a4/cordova-2.2.0.js:2753:5)
at download (http://localhost/~binderf/www/a4/js/index.js:194:5)
at downloadImage (http://localhost/~binderf/www/a4/js/index.js:182:9)
at Element.<anonymous> (http://localhost/~binderf/www/a4/js/index.js:153:51)
at Function.p.extend.each (http://localhost/~binderf/www/a4/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2:14477)
at p.fn.p.each (http://localhost/~binderf/www/a4/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2:11151)
at Element.<anonymous> (http://localhost/~binderf/www/a4/js/index.js:145:57)
at Function.p.extend.each (http://localhost/~binderf/www/a4/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2:14477)
at p.fn.p.each (http://localhost/~binderf/www/a4/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2:11151) ripple.js:477
FileTransfer 

FileTransfer ripple.js:483
download ripple.js:483
missing exec:FileTransfer.download
```

an dialog popped up with the message :

> FileTransfer.download

We seem to be missing some stuff :(

What is kinda cool though you can fill in the textarea to pass a json object to the callback you want to execute.

I see its undefined but I can't figure out what is really my problem. If anyone has a guess or a similar problem please any suggestion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because Ripple plugin for Chrome has not implemented this feature. It will work in real environment (e.g. phone).

Comment: You cannot use plugins. If you want to interact with the OS, you will need to use a real device. (The iOS simulator works quite well)

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach Yes. But he uses [Ripple](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc) plugin for Chrome which tries to emulate real device in browser window.

Comment: I know, but the key is "tries to emulate real device". This emulator will NEVER work with custom plugins. I think the chrome browser have to be started with a dropped security policy in order to use filesystems. I gave up using emulators (expect iOS emulator), they hide real problems and show emulator-only problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, i was kind of confused.. but makes sense that this is not implemented yet. Yeah in a real environment it works fine (also on emulator) for me, it would just nice for debugging.. :) so i go on with Xcode and emulator... someone of you had experience with code edge ? i am still not happy with the workflow.. so i try fig our out wich it the most efficient way to design/develop/debug

Comment: @user1921446 We solved this by adding a boolean constant RIPPLE to code. When is set to true, we skip the FileTransfer code.
It's not ideal solution but it works in our case.