# File.requestAllPaths, We seem to be missing some stuff

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ripple

I just installed VS 2013 update 4 and visual studio for Cordova after that.
I got the following message posted with success and fail button option to click every time I ran my simple app.

> "File.requestAllPaths
>   We seem to be missing some stuff
>   What is kinda cool though you can fill in the text area to pass a json object to the callback you want to execute"

The JavaScript console debugger shows the following messages:

> "missing exec:File.requestAllPaths
>   File: ripple.js, Line: 40, Column: 28710
>   ...
>   requestAllPaths
>   File: ripple.js, Line: 48, Column: 12284"

Is that missing some functions in the ripple.js at runtime? What caused the problem? How can I fix it?
Thanks a lot,

Tuan

Comment: Used cite style for some parts of cited errors

Answer (score 2):

It's because Ripple plugin for Chrome has not implemented this feature. It will work in real environment (e.g. phone).
Look at [Phonegap Filetransfer.download Ripple/Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990816/phonegap-filetransfer-download-ripple-chrome)